# ISO8601 formatted string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, iso8601

I have the following ISO8601 formatted date time string:

*2016-03-28T16:07:00+0200*

I want to convert it into a C# `DateTime` object, but the parsing method I'm using throws an exception.

**Currently I have this: (Does not work)**

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+zzzz";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

// Throws the exception: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-03-28T16:07:00+0200", format, provider);
```

How do I get the parse function to work with my string?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  What do you want to do that you're having trouble with?

Comment: I want to use the the date in my c# program. The way i currently do it does not work.

Comment: What do you want to do with it?  We can't help if we can't understand the problem. :/

Comment: I want to do comparisons with other DateTime variables in my program

Comment: How does this not work?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, String was not recognized as valid DateTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `DateTime time = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-28T16:07:00+0200");`.  Your string seems to be a [format that will be recognized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#StringToParse) by [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of DateTime.

```
var dateString = "2016-03-28T16:07:00+0200";
var date = DateTimeOffset.Parse (dateString);

Console.WriteLine (date.ToString ());
```

If you want to convert to DateTime object

```
date.UtcDateTime;
```

It will emit:

```
3/28/2016 4:07:00 PM +02:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i want to convert it to a DateTime object, so i can use that object for comparisons further in my program.

Comment: You can easily convert to whatever object you want. Point is DateTimeOffset works best with different time zones.

Comment: @Evert see `.UtcDateTime` property of DateTimeOffset